# Prevent focus on Chrome WebDriver window when using get_screenshot_as_png()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm utilizing Selenium with Python to capture screenshots using `driver.get_screenshot_as_png()`. Unfortunately, each time I invoke this function, the Chrome WebDriver window gains focus, which is causing inconvenience in my computer usage.

I have attempted using headless mode (`--headless`), but it didn't meet my requirements as `get_screenshot_as_png()` behaves differently in that mode.

How  to achieve screenshot capture without bringing the WebDriver window to the top?